# How to remove a Super Table row on the front end?

Tags: plugin-supertable, frontend-form

Is it possible to remove a Super Table row?

I got it to work to add a new row but it would be great if I can remove it later.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: With or without php/a custom controller?

Comment: without a custom controller

Comment: In that case you need to submit the exact same form just without the row you want to remove.

Comment: No I got a better solution! If the type of the field is 0 then it is removed! So I solve it with a bit javascript

Comment: @Samuel can you add what worked for you as an official solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution!

```
<input class="remove" type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ row.id }}][type]" value="{{ blocktype }}">
```

So the output will be "1" if you change it to "0" and safe your page the row is deleted! Really simple.